# Flicker on jQuery Background Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, preload

I created a jsfiddle for my current code. http://jsfiddle.net/gL5sB/38/

I am trying to change the body background css on scroll event. When the background changes it appears to flicker when the css is updated and new image is loaded. At times it seems smooth and then it seems to get worse. Very strange. Curious if anyone knows how to optimize?

I am preloading the images. Not sure why the flicker. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    switchImage();
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    switchImage();
});

var pics = []; // CREATE PICS ARRAY

//PRELOAD FUNCTION TO SET UP PICS ARRAY IN MEMORY USING IMAGE OBJECT
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        pics[i] = new Image();
        pics[i].src = arguments[i];
        //alert("preload " + arguments[i]);
    }
}
preload(
    'bgImage/100.jpg',
    'bgImage/101.jpg',
    'bgImage/102.jpg',
    'bgImage/103.jpg',
    'bgImage/104.jpg',
    'bgImage/105.jpg',
    'bgImage/106.jpg',
    'bgImage/107.jpg',
    'bgImage/108.jpg',
    'bgImage/109.jpg',
    'bgImage/110.jpg',
    'bgImage/111.jpg',
    'bgImage/112.jpg',
    'bgImage/113.jpg'
);

function switchImage() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop()/10;
    var index = Math.floor(s / 5);

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + pics[index].src + ')');
}
```

Comment: Shawn, it looks quite smooth for me on chrome (windows).  Where are you seeing the flickering?  As a separate issue from your question, these images themselves are nearly a 1MG all together, which is quite a large page load just to get a bg image.

Comment: I do agree, but the images have been optimized from original size. So, is your suggestion to reduce the image sizes further? There are actually 200 images running to give a movie effect. Good to read that it is working on your machine. Does it still respond well when you scroll slowly? I will see if we can reduce the images further.

Comment: Well, no matter what you do they will still be pretty big.  I am suggesting that you're paying a pretty steep price for a cool effect, so you might want to consider not using it.  Ignoring that for now, though, I tried your fiddle in IE and was able to see the flickering effect.  I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: It seems that it happens when the images haven't finished preloading, and on my sort of slow DSL connection it takes up to 10 seconds for the loading to finish.  There's nothing you will be able to do to prevent this, since you have no control over your user's internet connection speed.  One suggestion would be this: use `onload` to separately keep track of when each of your images is finished preloading.  Then *only* execute the switchImage code with the index is for an image that has finished preloading.

Comment: I understand Jonah, but the only issue is that I have to use this effect and code. My other solution was use HTML5 video background and figuring out how to play forwards and reverse, but this seemed like a much better solution.

Comment: I can try the onload suggestion. It could be that I use a static method that loads part on preload. I will need to play around with this and see what I come up with for a solution. I wish that i didnt have to create this effect, but it is apart of the gig and a must have. So, I am going to keep playing with it. It does look really cool though on the main site when fully loaded.

Comment: I would expect a video version to compress better and load faster than multiple images. It also avoids the frame load problem altogether

Comment: Do you specifically need to read in the images? I mean; are they delivered in a certain format beyond your control (on release), or would drawing that content (and frame-updates) yourself be an option too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is OK. I can see the flicker in IE. A Solution for that is at the bottom of this post.

I suspect A video version would compress and load faster than all the images, but as suggested by @Allendar drawing it would be the most transmission efficient. I would suggest canvas or SVG.

Another way using images along would be to have individual components as either images or icon fonts placed on the display with absolute positioning and then just turning them on or off in script. But that's a very complex solution.

I think the simplest and fastest method for you to solve the issue today though would be to just tweak the solution you have. As other people have suggested, the multiple images approach won't be super efficient and if you're going to take that route at least make sure you set the caching headers on your web server to cache indefinitely;

```
Cache-Control: public;
Expires: Mon, 31 Dec 2035 12:00:00 GMT
```

OK, so the flicker problem is just a bug/inefficiency in the rendering engine in IE, so here's a workaround that uses a different approach.

Basically stretch an absolutely positioned `DIV` over the `body`, instead of using the `body` itself. In fact, in this case we use multiple `DIV`s, one for each image and overlay them on top of one another. You could create these nodes in script as well.

Secondly, add another `DIV` for your content, and overlay that over the `body` as well;

```
<body>
    <div id="b100" class="background" style="background-image:url('http://ingodwetrustthemovie.com/bgImage/100.jpg')"></div>
    <!-- rest omitted -->
    <div id="b113" class="background" style="background-image:url('http://ingodwetrustthemovie.com/bgImage/113.jpg')"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="test">test div</div>
        here is some text
    </div>
</body>
```

The simply show one at a time and hide the rest;

```
function switchImage() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop()/10;
    var index = Math.floor(s / 5);

    $('.background').hide();
    $('.background').eq(index).show();
}
```

I had a suspicion that twiddling the css display option would be less flickery than changing the src attribute and it seems to do the trick.

#### Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZU8a/1/)

Of course you may still need to optimise the code to allow for the first loaded image to be shown first instead of the plain background, but I think this demonstrates the principle of a fix.

You could also consider making a very large CSS Sprite, by bundling the images into one huge strip and then using `background-position`. That would probably work on the `body` tag itself then. Of course this would mean downloading a huge file before you can display any images at all, but there are two advantages;

1. One image (especially with such similarity) will compress way better than each individual one in isolation.
2. Using the same caching directives, that's only one HTTP/GET/302 cycle instead of 13 once you've fetched the image the first time, so your page may load faster still.

### SVG

SVG elements work much like the DOM. If you can get your content delivered as an SVG you can drill into the graphic, locate the elements, give them IDs etc, and manipulate them much like you would any other DOM element;

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <ellipse id="e1" cy="420" cx="200" rx="420" ry="30" style="fill:3f5566" />
   <ellipse id="e2" cy="420" cx="170" rx="390" ry="20" style="fill:4f5566" />
   <ellipse id="e3" cy="420" cx="145" rx="370" ry="15" style="fill:5f5566" />
   <ellipse id="e4" cy="420" cx="100" rx="370" ry="20" style="fill:6f5566" />
   <ellipse id="e5" cy="420" cx="45"  rx="300" ry="15" style="fill:8f5566" />
</svg>
```

Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danieljsinclair/Kcah9/) that hides/unhides SVG elements based on a scroll.

Ideally, assuming they've generated that graphic in 'layers', try and have your designers deliver you an SVG where the layers are converted into [groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#Groups). Adobe Illustrator can [do that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6360a.html) for instance.

Then you can easily turn off the layers/groups as necessary to create the animated effect.

Comment: Thanks cirrus. I will certainly check this out. Was trying to use divs instead of background, but was running out of time on the project. Had a three week turn around on the site and was crazy with the other projects. I have seen the fix for updating the htaccess with setting the headers correctly. I concur that a sprite might be one of the easiest solutions. They design firm gave us a vid, but the images seemed like an easier path forwards. Thanks for the heads up... will dig in soon.

Comment: I just read that you have 200 images. In which case I'd be inclined to go with video rather than statics. However, drawing vectors is still the best option. Can you get the designers to give you the SVG instead? Just use that in place of images to begin with, but with more time you could optimise it to display just the components you need.

Comment: I can see about obtaining the SVG and asking Monday. I have not used SVG so, am going to start researching now. They did supply us with a mp4, but I had no idea how to load and play the video forwards and backwards based on the scroll event which is why I went with the images. We had to launch the site in a hurry. Since it is up ad running it is more like a personal interest to get this thing running smoothly. Seriously thank you for the support and feedback. I am going to dive into the code first thing Monday morning based on the research that I figure out.

Comment: See updated answer with an SVG demo. You could have them deliver multiple SVG frames and use them the same way you did images, but it would be far better I think if you have one SVG and drill into it by hand and pick out the elements needed for each frame and turn them on or off selectively. You could add a class="frame1", class="frame2" for instance.

Comment: Thanks man. You rock. I am pounding my head on another project. Will give a look Thursday due to schedule, but will for sure let you know what happens. I am going to give you the bounty for helping me out. Sincerely appreciate your knowledge and help on this Cirrus.

Comment: Thanks! BTW - just added note about 'layers' to the end of the post whilst you were doing that.

Comment: For some reason the fiddle on svg wasnt working for me in FF, but I can try and look a little later and see what is happening.

Comment: I've fixed that for FF now.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use one image (sprite image) and just move it with `background-position` instead of replacing the image?
(about the size - you can set percentage based `background-size` in your case - the height will be `1400%`

Because your'e preloading all the images anyway - it won't cost you in page loading time - and it might also save some time because with the right compression 1 image of 14 will weight less then 14 images of 1

Answer (score 2):

If the images aren't really needed, you can create some system for yourself where you draw, and keep updating, the background using canvas. This would be start;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/4pFHC/)

**HTML**

```
<img id="template" src="http://ingodwetrustthemovie.com/bgImage/100.jpg" />
<canvas id="absBg" width="1000px" height="560px"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#template {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 563px;
}

#absBg {
    position: absolute;
    /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
'use strict';

function drawBlock(ctx, color, line_width, start, lines) {
    ctx.lineWidth = line_width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(start[0], start[1]);

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]);
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawBg() {
    var absBg = document.getElementById('absBg');
    var ctx = absBg.getContext('2d');

    var demo_red = 'red';
    var grey = '#28282';

    var color = demo_red;

    drawBlock(ctx, color, 1, [185, 87], [[205, 75], [226, 98], [207, 110]]);
    drawBlock(ctx, color, 1, [235, 60], [[253, 50], [272, 71], [254, 81]]);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    drawBg();

    // Scroll trigger
    $(window).scroll(function () {

    });
});
```

The demo uses the actual background image you have as a background-model, where you can draw over with the canvas. This way you can mimick the look of the original image you have.

You can try to manage some kind of "difference-array" where you store which blocks are different on which locations. This way you can trigger the function on `scroll` with certain parameters to let it change the drawing based on that.

I hope for you that you don't "need" the images per se. Drawing with canvas is so much faster than loading tons of images :)

Comment: Thanks Allendar. I agree drawing would be better. I had all the drawings supplied by a design firm along with the vid version. I went with the array since I was running out of time and put this together rapidly. I am going to give a stab at this solution as well and see if it is viable. I do sincerely appreciate the feed back. Will sort this out and let you know the results.

Comment: Allendar, I do you have a link to a tut about drawing canvas. To be honest I dont have any experience but I can dig into and see where i end up. Seriously, thanks.

Comment: @ShawnAltman Glad to hear it's a possible solution. Personally I like these sites as reference; http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/integrating/. The internet crawls with awesome Canvas tutorials and examples; https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html5+canvas. Good luck!

Comment: Oh by the way, one more tip; You could draw two absolute `<canvas>` objects over each other too. Where all the shapes that are *always* there are drawn on the lowest `<canvas>`. This way you only *re-draw* changing shapes on the front `<canvas>`, which will make the "rendering-load" on your visitor's browser even lighter than is and also separates the big list of *shape-drawings* in the original background from the smaller list of changing shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works (2014.7.11) at firefox 30.0, chrome 35.0, opera 22.0, ie 11.0:

**STEP 1: add these lines at .htaccess**:

```
# cache for images
<FilesMatch "\.(png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=10000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

- **detailed description of this problem and how to fix it**:
  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102706

**STEP 2: add images preloading, for example**:

```
var pics = []; // CREATE PICS ARRAY

$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    preload(
        '/public/images/stars.red.1.star.png',
        '/public/images/stars.red.2.star.png',
        '/public/images/stars.red.3.star.png',
        '/public/images/stars.red.4.star.png',
        '/public/images/stars.red.5.star.png',
        '/public/images/stars.empty.png'
    );
    ...
    $('.rating').on('mousemove', function(event){
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var id = getIdByCoord(x); //
        if ($(this).data('current-image') != id) {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + pics[id].src + ')');
            $(this).data('current-image', id);
        }
    })
    ...
})

...

// PRELOAD FUNCTION TO SET UP PICS ARRAY IN MEMORY USING IMAGE OBJECT
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        pics[i] = new Image();
        pics[i].src = arguments[i];
        // alert("preload " + arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

P.S. thanks Shawn Altman