# background-attachment fixed not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I tried google for help on this and it seems to be a bug in chrome but I still can't find a solution. I have taken a look at many stackoverflow questions similar to this but those solutions still didn't help.

When I try to scroll down on the page the background-image flickers and messes up. 
I am using Google Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 on Ubuntu Desktop

CSS code:

```
#left-container {
background-image: url('http://easource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/traphouse4.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: -1% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can see how it looks on http://easource.com

Also, I tried removing the background-position but still doesn't work.

Comment: i using Chrome for Mac 36.0.1985.125, it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

As seen here: [Fixed attachment background image flicker/disappear in chrome when coupled with a css transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268962/fixed-attachment-background-image-flicker-disappear-in-chrome-when-coupled-with)

Try to change to `position:static` only.

Comment: I removed background-attachment:fixed and the background-position. The page now looks fine in chrome except that I wanted the image to be fixed so that when you scroll down the bg image doesn't scroll as well.

Comment: But just changing the background-position to 'static', leaving the attachment, doesn't work for you?

Comment: Any other suggestions someone?

Comment: My background image with `background-attachment: fixed` would disappear momentarily when I scrolled. `position:static` fixed it for me. Thanks! (Not `background-position:static` which isn't actually a thing.)

Comment: Nothing fixed it for me, tried various solutions to no avail.  Chrome SUCKS, and I don't know why anyone would use it.  For me it's almost as bad as IE.  Tested on Chrome for Android v64.0.3282

Answer (score 5):

You can keep your position as is and add the transform property to your background image element.

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: this is still a thing in 2018. this is the best answer; changing to position:static has too many drawbacks and messes up other positioning for children; this affects nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `overflow-y: scroll;`
from `body` solved the issue for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue where a parallax background was not showing up. Surprisingly adding the following css rule fixed the issue:
`.wpv-parallax-bg-img {    overflow-y: scroll !important; }`
 I haven't noticed any unexpected side effects but this is only reviewed in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `backface-visibility: hidden;`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine with using `position:static`;
if it doesn't work, remove the `position` property.

Comment: The css position property affects the content, while background attachment only affect the background image.

Answer (score -3):

You must have to use these properties to make the image fixed:

```
background-image: URL("your image path");
```

and I'm 100% sure that it will work for you in every browser.