# why background image jerks while scrolling when using css as background-attachment:scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am using `background-attachment:scroll` for two divs, Scrolling works perfectly but only the issue is background image jerks while scrolling. I am attaching my CSS below:

```
.slider_area {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:#9ad5e3 url(../images/slide_1.jpg) center top no-repeat; 
    background-attachment:scroll;
    -webkit-background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:cover;
}

.cont_1_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:100px 0;
    background:url(../images/cont_1_bg_b.jpg) repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
}

<script>

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.scroll').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
    });

</script>
```

JSFIDDLE LINK : https://jsfiddle.net/ansarmon/apxrztat/1/

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you share jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Are you on a mac? Also what type of Image ext (jpg / png / gif etc)? Did you optimize the image (is it 2 - 3mb)?

Comment: @Cam both mac and windows showing same jerking, Image format jpg and below 350 kb resolution.

Comment: @Madan Bhandari, https://jsfiddle.net/ansarmon/apxrztat/1/

Comment: It's working fine in jsfiddle. what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: @Madan Bhandari, image is jerking while scrolling that's the issue. an up and movement in the image.

Comment: @ansarmon it's working perfectly on my pc. If you are talking about top blank space, then use margin-top for .main_wrapper

Comment: Works perfectly for my mac too without any jerks. Did you test it on some other computer? Does your jsfiddle also show jerks?

Comment: @Madan Bhandari, can u pls scroll up and down slowly using scroll bar on right background image will jerk.

Comment: yeah, I got it, Have you checked with higher resolution ? If not try with high resolution image.

Comment: @ Naisheel Verdhan , I tried in ipad too, there is also the same issue.

Comment: @ Madan Bhandari , I checked with a png image , same issue is there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

to `.slider_area`

Comment: Yes... same by using mouseweel... but in your fiddle after i added this, flickering stopped while i use scrollbar. Try answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268962/fixed-attachment-background-image-flicker-disappear-in-chrome-when-coupled-with

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-attachment:fixed; for fixed background image. No need of jquery.

```
.slider_area 
{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:#9ad5e3 url(http://www.pro.net.in/demo/cheetahbridge/images/slide_1.jpg) center top no-repeat;   
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62jv0nz5/

Comment: before I used same background-attachment:fixed; but the issue is not supported in  ipad and mobile. So turned to use it.

Comment: Yes. looks like background-attachment:fixed; have some issues. Eventhough it've a good support. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

Comment: yes, older versions of browsers not supporting these codes. that's the main issue. I am trying to get rid of it.

Comment: OK. Anyway if you are trying to create a parallax website you could always use libraries like skrollr, which removes developer headache.