# background-attachment fixed with transform not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background, transform, background-attachment

CSS value transform turn off `background-attachment: fixed` in Firefox.

Here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r8ec20qL/)

```css
div {
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0); // if remove starts to work
   width: 100%;
   height: 2000px;
   background-image: url('http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/001_Fish-Wallpaper-HD_hkNsK33.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

if you remove transform from CSS it starts to work. Reproducible only in FF.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anybody know a work around?

Comment: That's a bug it's not fixed yet

Comment: not sure why a bounty, this is a known bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1304985

Comment: according to firefox this is intentional due to https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=17521. I have explained the reason of why a bounty that is I need a workaround. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @AbdulRabMemon you won't find a generic workaround for that since it's a bug, it will depend on each sitatuion, I have faced this bug a lot of time and each time I find a way to avoid it and make it working on FF ... So if you have a  particular case share it and we will find solution for it but don't expect a magic workaround

Comment: In My particular case there is a swiper(react-id-swiper) this swiper uses transform and in that swiper is this exact same site http://www.philanthropyage.org/coming-of-age-2018/.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated @TemaniAfif

Comment: @AbdulRabMemon what swiper? I don't see any issue with the website, it works the same in FF and Chrome

Comment: I'm trying to put it in a swiper and other articles all articles will be swipeable.

Comment: The combination does not work in any browser.

Answer (score 6):

> `background-attachment:fixed;` doesn't work when any 'transform' is
>   applied

and that's a bug in firefox and it is not yet fixed.

Reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292499

Comment: Sadly that bug report was seen as invalid as browser handle `background-attachment: fixed` as `background-attachment: scroll` _on purpose_ during transforms. Is there a way one could replace `background-attachment: fixed` to make it look right during transforms?

Answer (score 1):

It was a common problem 2 years ago, but as far as I know, it has been solved a while ago, and now the `background-attachment` CSS Property is now fully supported by all browsers, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

Comment: Although `fixed` isn't supported by iOS Safari and Samsung Internet yet: [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment).

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) when it comes to animations most background properties are discrete. Except for the background-size and background-position properties.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32320553)

Comment: That's true I'll take not of that

Comment: The fact that properties are discrete for animations has nothing to do with this issue in my opinion. Or maybe I don't get your answer.

Answer (score -3):

This has been solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268962/fixed-attachment-background-image-flicker-disappear-in-chrome-when-coupled-with).

Long story short- use `position` instead of `background-attachment`.

Comment: This has not been solved in that question, that question provides solution to another problem.

Comment: @AbdulRabMemon why adding a bounty to a known bug?