# Triangle after header that matches header background gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have to make a header like this:

[image: Header]

I have no problem in making the header with this gradient. I also know how to position a triangle with `::after`. However, how can I make the triangle color to match header background? The problem is that the gradient is not static. For example, if I open the page in a smartphone, as the screen is shorter, the gradient will be more "compact" than if I open in a monitor. So the arrow color can't be static. I have no idea how I could do this, can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clip-path` to mask the header:

```css
header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60px, calc(100% - 40px) 60px, calc(100% - 60px) 70px, calc(100% - 80px) 60px, 0 60px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3f5efb, #fc466b);
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

With this option you're going to have to provide fallbacks for browsers that don't support `clip-path`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea more supported without the use of `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,purple,red);
  background-attachment:fixed; /*This will do the magic*/
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,purple,red);
  background-attachment:fixed; /*This will do the magic*/
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  right:20px;
  bottom:-10px;
  animation:slide 5s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
     right:20px;
  }
  to {
    right:calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

The above soltution is not working with Firefox due to a bug with `background-attachment:fixed` and the use of `transform`. Here is another idea that should work:

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,purple,red);
  background-attachment:fixed; /*This will do the magic*/
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:10px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to right,purple,red);
  background-attachment:fixed; /*This will do the magic*/
  right:20px;
  bottom:-10px;
  animation:slide 5s infinite alternate linear;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width:20px;
  height:10px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,white 51%)100% 0/50% 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,white 51%)0 0/50% 100% no-repeat;
  right:20px;
  bottom:-10px;
  animation:slide 5s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
     right:20px;
  }
  to {
    right:calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it didn't work here. Diamond gradient is static.

Comment: @MateusFelipe what are you using ?

Comment: Firefox 59.0.2.

Comment: @MateusFelipe true ... in chrome it's working fine ... maybe we discovered a bug :) will look into it ...it seems related to the transform

Comment: @MateusFelipe well it seems to be a know issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633745/background-attachment-fixed-with-transform-not-works-in-firefox ... at the end my solution wasn't more supported :p ... but i will find a work around ;)