# Background-attachment fixed with transform not works in Firefox 2018

Tags: firefox, transform, background-attachment

Hello everybody I have a problem with my code under, background-attachment fixed work only when I remove transform: rotate() in Firefox and IE instead working great in Chrome.

This is my HTML

```
        <div class="para">

        </div>
```

This is my css

```
.para{
  z-index: -100;
  height: 160vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -40rem;
  background: url("back1.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 22%, 100% 0, 100% 79%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 22%, 100% -800px, 100% 60%, 0% 100%);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

So for being clear when I remove translate property is working everywhere when I add it is working only in chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background-attachment fixed with transform not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633745/background-attachment-fixed-with-transform-not-working-in-firefox)