# background-attachment: fixed not working as expected in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to implement the following codepen for my website :

https://codepen.io/pizza3/pen/NgXowe

When opened with chrome the background images of the slices are positionned correctly and all the slices stacked on each other will display the entire image.

However when browsing with firefox (version Qunatum 60.0.1 (64-bit)) you can notice that the background images are not positionned the same. Seems to me it has to do with the origin point of the images or something similar but I can't figure what the problem is.

I believe the relevant part of the problem is here :

```
.left,
.right {
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 20vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Is this a firefox bug ?

In other words how can I have the same background image spread accross multiple DIVs ?

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

EDIT

Here a couple screenshots to illustrate the problem:

Chrome : 
 [image: chrome]

Firefox : 
[image: firefox]

Comment: I don't see your issue on Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 OSX. Could you post a screen shot ?

Comment: Apart from it being a bit jittery at the edges when the animation is running, I am not able to spot any significant differences in Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit) on Win 10.

Comment: Edited my question qith a couple screenshots so you can see exactly what my problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that, though counter-intuitive, the behavior of Firefox(and Edge) is [intended](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=735857) and correct as per spec: the `transform` property (used by the GSAP library for animation) makes `background-attachment: fixed` behave as `scroll`. So I'd suggest removing `background-attachment: fixed` and replacing it with different `background-position` values for each slice of the image.

May be this answer would also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067630/2533215

Comment: Do you suggest calculating the pixel position of the background for each slide and then setting it with javascript ?

Comment: No, since all slices have the same height, you can combine percentages with `vh` units to calculate positions with CSS itself, e.g. like in this forked example: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/eKJjQb