# Fix background image position in Firefox (Bootstrap carousel)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use [this](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-half-slider/) bootstrap template.
I want make carousel background images fixed, but when I add

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

like this

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="
background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080');
background-attachment: fixed;
">
```

I get what I what in chrome, but in firefox it works strange.
In firefox, when slide is moving, image is not fixed. After slide stops, image is fixed. I didn't find reason why is this happening.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make slide background image fixed, when I scroll page.
Like this, but for slide: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. It took me a while to figure out what is going on.

Bootstrap carousel uses `transform: translateX();` to do its animating.

```
.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left),
.active.carousel-item-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right),
.active.carousel-item-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Transform translate will move the fixed background image left or right, regardless if the background is fixed. Unlike position or anything else, the background image stays fixed where ever the element moves. It's a bummer.

I tried to hack it for ages, by putting an extra div with an extra child div for the background, but I could not get my head round the classes. I was trying to reverse translate the background image when the slide is transitioning to give the effect of it being fixed, but then the background image on the next slide needs to not animate. Very confusing. Not sure how this can be done with a slider that uses translate to do its animating. https://www.codeply.com/go/vzVI1YkwYc

Maybe someone clever can figure this one out.

Comment: Seems that it is a bug in firefox, and it's still not fixed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633745/background-attachment-fixed-with-transform-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: The thing is I can't even get the background to stay fixed in chrome on mac. Can you get this to work in chrome as expected? https://www.codeply.com/go/JDKtgxICPt

Comment: Heres another idea, but does not work on the last slide https://www.codeply.com/go/QbMKoAKA3T