# Pseudo element ::after does not respect background-attachment fixed?

Tags: css, background

I want to have a fixed background image on an ::after element. I am using this (valid) shorthand to do so:

```
 &::after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
height: 6vw;
transform: translateY(2vw) rotate(2deg) skewX(2deg);
background: url('../img/marmer.jpg') no-repeat center center/ cover transparent fixed;}
```

The backgrond image is there(of course), but despite the background-attachment being set as "fixed" it is behaving as "scroll". I did do searching but could not find confirmation this cannot work. Does anybody ever got this working?

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve], please.

Comment: the issue is the transform .. it's a bug, when transformed fixed no more work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633745/background-attachment-fixed-with-transform-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Ok, the transform is the issue. In FireFox a confirmed bug, but Webkit en Blink have the same issue. Thanks, I will find another solution.