# background-attachment: fixed breaking with translateX(0)

Tags: css, background-attachment

I have a scrolling element with a fixed background:

```css
.my-element {
   background: url(/foo.png) no-repeat right bottom;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

It works great! Normally. However, if I apply a translate transform (even of 0) to it (which I need for an animation), the background shifts to be non-fixed (it anchors to the bottom of .my-element, which is scrolled out of view:

```css
.my-element {
   background: url(/foo.png) no-repeat right bottom;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   transform: translateX(0); // this breaks the "fixed" behavior
}
```

There was a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39633745/954986), but the answers from 4 years ago say the bug has been fixed, and that it was only firefox. This is happening to me in Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a way I can avoid this? Or is there a way to get the same behavior w/o the background-attachment property? Thanks!

**edit:** just added a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mozges0k/7/

Comment: Can you provide us your real world use case (on CodePen or something else)? I cannot tell you about the bug, but I can help you with finding a workaround.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mozges0k/7/

Comment: I'd like to use background-attachment here, but if I can't are there any alternatives?

Comment: It is a known issue. You may absolutely postion the backround. https://css-tricks.com/the-fixed-background-attachment-hack/

Answer (score 2):

I had a pretty hard time finding a workaround. Extracting the background image to its own container and adding `position: sticky` to it seemed like a viable solution, but it didn't work out in the end.

There is one more solution that came to my mind: What if you extract `transform` to its own class and remove that class when the animation has finished? It seems like `background-attachment` starts working again when `transform`is removed, even at runtime. Then the `background-attachment` can do its magic and your animation can run too.

```html
<div class="my-element animate">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

```css
.my-element {
    background: url(/foo.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.animate {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```js
function animationFinished() {
    const target = document.querySelector('.animate');
    target.classList.remove('animate')
}
```

While its not as easy and direct as I would like it to be, this *would* be a solution.
Let me know what you think, and good luck!

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one who struggled with it. The problem is that the background is visible during the transform (I'm sliding from one route to another in React), and it flickers if the attachment is removed (or if it breaks due to transform).

Comment: I ended up extracting the background out of the transformed container, putting it as a fixed 0,0,0,0 element. It sort of works, but the background remains stationary when sliding between routes instead of sliding horizontally with the rest of the content, which I don't like (and which makes it harder to have different backgrounds on different pages, so I'm stuck with one background for the site)

Comment: Here's the site if you're curious (plus I've been working on it a lot and want to show someone lol): https://distant.land/ The background I'm referencing is only on the desktop version. I just migrated it from Scala to TypeScript + React, and still need to re-add some features like comments. I'm trying to build a bit of a Google Firebase clone on the backend for fun.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean. Its a shame that this doesn't work properly, it shouldn't be that way. Sure, its a good feeling to show fellow dev's what one is working on :) Great stuff!

Comment: Thanks! And if you get any ideas for workarounds let me know. I'm tempted to set an absolute top offset with Javascript with an onscroll event, but am worried that would cause some flickering of the background while scrolling.

Comment: @Nathan this can probably be achieved with framer-motion if it's a route animation

Comment: I'm using something similar to framer motion, that works similar to how it does. The slide animation between routes works well, the issue is that it works by applying a translateX to the main content container, and that breaks the background-fixed attachment in the content (because it messed with the coordinates, from what I gather).

Answer (score 2):

### Background

I dig into the topic a bit, and I find that this behavior is NOT a bug. It's actually *conforming* to the spec.

In the beginning things used to behave like you (and most of us) thought it should: `background-attachment: fixed` should fix the background relative the the viewport.

Turns out it's simply too hard to implement the fixing behavior when `transform` is involved, and thus the [spec authors decided](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=17521) that "we might just change the spec to make things easier."

And now the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property) says:

> Fixed backgrounds on the root element are affected by any transform specified for that element. For all other elements that are effected by a transform (i.e. have a transform applied to them, or to any of their ancestor elements), a value of "fixed" for the "background-attachment" property is treated as if it had a value of "scroll".

which basically say `transform` invalidates `background-attachment: fixed`, explains everything.

### Solution

I'd propose use a fixed-size scroll container, which is the same size as the viewport, with `overflow: scroll`. It serves as the a background bearer, and you apply transform to it.

Now because it's same size as viewport, vertical scroll wouldn't behave any different. But you can still `transform: translateX(n)` it however you want.

```js
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.scroll-container')
const contentContainer = document.querySelector('.content-container')

const p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerText = text.repeat(20)

contentContainer.appendChild(p)

const btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollContainer.style = 'transform: translateX(-1000px);'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scroll-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red; 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  overflow: scroll;
  
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/PcqkZxh.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <button id="btn">
      move
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a 2 containers(elements) then you can try below work around:

Creating a parent container for the element which you are transforming(translate)

--> You can position the parent element as relative

--> Create an another container for the image position it absolute

```
   .container-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/PcqkZxh.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Then you are good to go with any transform animation on the container with a fixed background image

```css
.foo {
  display: "none";
  flex-direction: "row";
}

.container-parent-broken {
  position: relative;
}

.container-broken {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.container-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/PcqkZxh.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
  Scroll to see the difference
</h1>

<div style="display: flex; column-gap: 20px;">

  <div class="container-parent-broken">
    <div class="container-image"></div>

    <div class="container-broken">
      <h1>
        This doesn't (translateX(0))
      </h1>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly the workaround I ended doing, but it's sub-optimal. It means I can't transform the background along with the rest of the page-- so I can't have the background slide out of view when changing Routes (I'm using React). I also can't have any other fixed elements on the page, which I wanted to have. Appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm still hoping to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

another way of working around this could be done using a grid layout inside the containers.

Using a grid of 1 column and 1 row and then assign both the image (a div with a background image in this example), and the content (wrapped in another div) to the same row and column.

You can then use position sticky on the image to have it stick when scrolling and use z-index: 0 on the content so it is visible on top.

difference would be that the background image would only start sticking when the container has reached the top of the viewport and stop sticking when scrolling past the element altogether.

You would now be able to use translateX to animate everything

```css
.container-working, .container-broken {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.container-broken {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.container-image, .container-content {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.container-image {
  position: sticky;
  
  top: -10px; /* because of border-radius it has to stick a bit higher */
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh + 20px); /* increase height by twice the border-radius */
    
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/PcqkZxh.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container-content {
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
Scroll to see the difference
</h1>

<div style="display: flex; gap: 20px; position:relative;">
  <div class="container-working">
    <div class=container-image></div>
    <div class=container-content>
      <h1>
        This works (fixed bg)
      </h1>
      <div>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-broken">
    <div class=container-image></div>
    <div class=container-content>
      <h1>
       This doesn't (translateX(0))
      </h1>
      <div>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the code it is working for me fine I have already faced that issue. I have added `background-size: cover;` & `transform: translateX(0)` in `keyframe` and I think it is working for you too.

.my-element {

```css
.my-element {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/PcqkZxh.jpg") no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove .1s alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: mymove .1s alternate ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
  }
} 

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
Scroll to see the difference
</h1>

<div class="my-element">
   <h1>
   This works (fixed bg)
   </h1>
  <div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Try adding a ` to { transform: translateX(-100)}` with a 15 second timeout, and you'll notice the same issue as in the jsfiddle I provided. The fixed attachment breaks during the transition.