# Filter:blur() working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have an image I want to blur on scroll. I've got it working fine in Chrome but in Firefox it seems to move...

https://jsfiddle.net/p88hy7wn/

I'm using `$window.scroll` and have the following to apply the filter...

```
$parallaxElement.css({
    'filter' : 'blur('+blurValue+'px)',
    '-webkit-filter' : 'blur('+blurValue+'px)',
    '-moz-filter' : 'blur('+blurValue+'px)'
});
```

Anybody have an idea of what's happening?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ebellempire/pen/rnvEK

Comment: http://css-plus.com/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/

Answer (score 2):

I need to update my answer completely. Your problem is not the blur filter. It is working fine. For better improvement for blur you can add

```
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;

   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -moz-perspective: 1000;
   -ms-perspective: 1000;
   perspective: 1000
```

But the lagg is triggered by the background-attachment: fixed; in mozilla.
Other Prefixes like transform are removing the background-attachment: fixed; completely.

```
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
```

I am trying to figure out why

Some Links if you wanna help searching:

[Fixed attachment background image flicker/disappear in chrome when coupled with a css transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268962/fixed-attachment-background-image-flicker-disappear-in-chrome-when-coupled-with)

The solution of the link above is not working as well^^ not sure why

Maybe you should just go with another solution of parallax.

Comment: Sry missed something

Comment: I see 1 sec. I have the solution. My answer didn't update mb

Comment: Appreciate the effort and input @Traver - I'll have a read, thanks!

Comment: The funny thing is if you remove the javascript completely its's lagging again. even with blur and background-attachement. The question is damn intresting

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.header-promo .img {
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```